# How to fix the problem that prevents a textbox from caching in jsp?I need to stop a particular text box from displaying the previously entered data

Tags: java, html, jsp, caching, jakarta-ee

I am trying to create a login page using J2EE. But, whenever I place the cursor on employee id, it displays the previous entries. This might be due to browser caching or caching from the database. How to fix this issue?

I have already tried using the following header code:-

```
 <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" contentType="text/html; 
charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", -1); 
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   < meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <title>
```

[Photo of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbGWG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the very old method of setting autocopmlete to off inside your input tag.

```
autocomplete="off"
```